# SQL prediction of stored procedure result

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, compare

Hi is there a way to know the resulting data set of a stored procedure?

Let's say we have `sp_1`

```
SELECT u.FirstName, u.LastName
FROM [Users] u
```

Is there a way to know that the results will be of the form

```
+-------------+-------------+
| FirstName   | LastName    |
+-------------+-------------+
```

So I could compare that stored procedure to another `sp_2`

```
SELECT u.FirstName, u.LastName
FROM [Users] u
```

to make sure that `sp_2` will also return something like

```
+-------------+-------------+
| FirstName   | LastName    |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I would like to be able to compare many stored procedure like that.

Comment: The result of a stored procedure can depend on its input. You can have if/else conditions within the procedure that all execute different queries.

Comment: If you need to do such comparisons, perhaps you should consider views or table valued functions instead (the latter is not supported by all dtabases).

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is for SQL Server 2012, [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

Comment: This is **HIGHLY** vendor-specific - so we would really need to know ***what database*** you're really using, when you're saying `sql` (because SQL is just the structured query language - used by **many** database systems.....)